# LaTeX: Large figure floats to the end of the chapter

Tags: latex, figure

I have a LaTeX-document using the class

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
```

and I changed some parameters for positioning the floats:

```
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1} %default: 0.7
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{1} %default: 0.3
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1} %default: 0.2
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1} %default: 0.6
\setcounter{topnumber}{3}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{3}
```

I have two graphics that should be among each other and fill one single page. I don't know why, but because LaTeX always splits both graphics on two pages, I put both graphics into one `figure`-environment. It doesn't matter whether I use `[ht]` or `[p]` the figure with both graphics moves to the end of the chapter. I don't get any overfull warnings. So I think it might not the reason that the figure is too large.

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{graphic1.pdf}
\newcaption{caption 1} % <-- using \usepackage{picins}
\label{fig:pic1}

\vspace{5mm}

\includegraphics{graphic2.pdf}
\newcaption{caption 2}
\label{fig:pic2}
\end{figure}
```

Is there someone, who can explain that behaviour of LaTeX and can recommend a solution.

Comment: This just doesn't seem right. A *single* figure can't be split across two pages, period. Your `.log` *must* reveal some clue as to what's happening.

Comment: @Werner: Maybe I described it not precisely enough: When I have both graphics in two separate figures, the graphics are split onto two pages. But when I use both graphics in one figure, it moves to the end of the chapter.

Comment: What this means is that the entire `figure` block is too large to fit within the text block, and is therefore left to be flushed at the end until it reaches a `\clearpage`. You should see an "Overfull `\vbox`" warning in your `.log` around the last page of the chapter. If you wish to have the page-wise `figure` on the page subsequent to where you called it, add `\usepackage{afterpage}` to your preamble and use `\afterpage{\begin{figure}[H] ... \end{figure}}` to set the figure.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard behaviour in latex because it takes care of all positioning. I personally wouldn't mess this up and would instead refer to the images.

If you nevertheless want to position them at the given line in the text:

**Use the package float and place your images this way.**

```
\usepackage{float}

\begin{figure}[H]
...
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The parameter `[H]` forces the figure to be at a certain position but it's not handled as a float anymore. My text is splited with lots of free space. `[ht]` and `[p]` are still not working......

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood the meaning of `\floatpagefraction`....

It describes the **minimum** size that a float must have, so that you can use `[p]`. Setting it to a value of 1 (100% of the page) makes definitely no sense.

**bad:**

```
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1}
```

**good:**

```
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.6} %default: 0.6
```

Default values generally are not so bad......

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have your images right where you want them to be, just use

/usepackage{float}

and edit your image code as follows.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{graphic1.pdf}
\newcaption{caption 1} % <-- using \usepackage{picins}
\label{fig:pic1}
\end{figure}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{graphic2.pdf}
\newcaption{caption 2}
\label{fig:pic2}
\end{figure}
```